# ReactNative and Android: 64 bit. New Google Play rules. What to do?

Tags: react-native, google-play, apk

So my question is, in order to be compliant with Google Play's 64bit requirement, do we need a separate 64bit .apk or will the usual steps to publish, create an .apk that is compatible with both 32bit and 64bit in a single apk work? or is that what the .aab is for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you upload an .apk it will include binaries for both 32 and 64 bit platforms.  The entire combined package will be downloaded by the user.

If you upload a bundle (.aab) users will only get the binary for their platform, making for a quicker download and less disk space used.

(Of course, this assumes you've correctly configured your app gradle to support the different platforms)